# How to convert python dict to Json file?

Tags: python

I am having the dict of data which is given below

```py
data = {
    "1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "2": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20],
}
```

Now I want this data to be saved into a json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to convert python dict to json file.

It is very easy in python, you can simply use json module of python to create a json for your data.

***Use the code below***

```py
import json
data = {
    "1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
    "2": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
}

# You can provide path + filename in-place of data.json 
with open("data.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

This create a file named `data.json` in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

`with open("new_file","w") as f: json.dump(data,f)`
json.dumps--is used to write a json to a file